# What is the most direct way to reproduce this printf-like format with ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, format

I've been thrown into ColdFusion for a very simple assignment. The application has some logic to display "help codes" (let's not get into what is a help code), however, the logic is buggy and needs to be fixed. Given a two-letters code, a 1-4 digits number, and another 1-2 digits number, I would need to display them like this `printf` call would:

```
printf("%s%04d%02d", letterCode, bigNumber, smallNumber);
```

If you're not familiar with the printf function, it accepts a format string (the first parameter), and writes the other variables in it according to the given format. `%s` means "write a string" and `%d` means "write a number"; `%0zd` means "write a number and pad it with zeroes so it's at least *z* characters long (so `%04d` means "write a number and pad it with zeroes so it lengths at least 4 digits).

Here are a few examples with `%s%04d%02d`:

```
"AD", 45, 12:  AD004512
"GI", 5121, 1: GI512101
"FO", 1, 0:    FO000100
```

However, it's my very first time with ColdFusion, and I couldn't find anything like `printf` or `sprintf` to format strings.

The other guy, who doesn't work here anymore, resorted to a (non-working) loop, and I thought it would be better to use library code instead of actually fixing the loop, since anyways I might need to do similar things again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<cfset bigNumberPadded = NumberFormat(bigNumber,"0000")>
<cfset smallNumberPadded = NumberFormat(smallNumber,"00")>
<cfoutput>#letterCode##bigNumberPadded##smallNumberPadded#<cfoutput>
```

Or alternatively... as suggested by bpanulla, and corrected by Leigh

```
<cfset args = ["AD", javacast("int", 45), javacast("int", 12)]>
<cfset output= createObject("java","java.lang.String").format("%s%04d%02d", args) >
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `NumberFormat` to pad a number with leading zeros in CF.

```
<cfoutput>#letterCode##NumberFormat(bigNumber, '0000')##NumberFormat(smallNumber, '00')#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of ways to do this in the Java layer underpinning ColdFusion. Here's one Java resource:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Make instances of the Java classes you need with CFOBJECT or CreateObject.

Comment: I know you can use Java with CF, but I hoped for a simpler way.

Comment: Henry mocked up the code above - just so you're aware that you don't actually need to write any Java or even make a separate program: it can all be done inline in the ColdFusion code, or even better in a reusable UDF or CF component method. I understand that writing Java can be intimidating if you're not otherwise familiar with the language. Using a simple Java object here and there can really make your life as a CF developer much easier.

Answer (score -1):

I am assuming you are displaying these to a webpage?  If so, I would use a switch/case statement.  Since you said "given a two-letter code...", a switch/case would work well.  For example:

```
<cfswitch expression="#twoLetterCode#">
    <cfcase value="aa12348">%s%04d%02d</cfcase>
    <cfcase value="bb23456">%s%05f%01e</cfcase>
    <cfcase value="cc97641">%s%08g%10j</cfcase>
    <cfdefaultcase>%s%04d%02d</cfdefaultcase>
</cfswitch>
```

Or you could use an if/else instead.  But the main point (to answer your question) is that in ColdFusion you just type out the display characters (be it help codes, or text, or whatever).  You don't need to use a special function to display text to the page.

Comment: Um, `printf` takes a format string, and formats the values passed to it accordingly. In this case, it would print the 2-char code, then print a 4-digit number (padding with zeroes if necessary), then a 2-digit number (again, padding with zeroes). Are you sure that's what your `<cfswitch>` is doing?

Comment: Nope, that's not what my code was doing.  Sorry, you gave very little information as to what you meant by "printf".  I assumed it was a function from a different language, but with thousands of languages out there...anybody's guess?

Comment: It's actually a popular function that took its origins many years ago in the C language, and since then it's been reused in several languages. At least Java and Scala sport a `printf` function (from the `PrintStream` class) and Python had (I think it's deprecated now) support for `printf`-like format strings. Thanks for trying to help anyways. :)

Comment: Also, when you reply to someone in a comment, you might want to write @username somewhere in your comment; it notifies the person there's been a reply. (For instance, if you want to reply to me, you could write @zneak in your comment.)

Comment: @zneak thanks for the tip about commenting.  I am kind of new to stackoverflow.  :)